# How to change bound model attribute dynamically

Tags: knockout.js

There is an array of strings and one input element. I want to edit any array member with that one input element depending on the conditions.

How to achieve something like this:

```
mymodel.setActiveArrayMember(1)
// now input is bound to an array member 1

mymodel.setActiveArrayMember(5)
// now input is bound to an array member 5

etc.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set up the active member as a computed observable:

```
var activeArrayMember = ko.computed(function()
{
    read: function()
    {
        return array()[activeIndex()];
    }
    write: function (value)
    {
        array()[activeIndex()] = value;
        array.valueHasMutated();
    }
});
```

This is assumuing that your array is an observable array. Lose the `()` if it isn't. Then have an observable for the index of the active member, and set that when you want to change the member:

```
activeIndex(5);
```

Bind your html to activeArrayMember, and it should all work.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But I can't figure out how to do the same but with more complex array members. Let's say there is an array: [{name: 'Jon', age: 34}, {name: 'Tom', age: 50}, ...] How to bind name property to an input? I tried data-bind='text:activeArrayMember.name', data-bind='text:activeArrayMember().name', data-bind='with:activeArrayMember, text:name' but none of it worked.

Comment: Can you add the html that you want to use with the active member, and the parent html element too?

Comment: This is not working example: http://jsfiddle.net/fc5yu/16/ hope this will give you an idea about what I want to do.

Comment: It does work, you just hadn't implemented my answer properly. I've updated the fiddle with the correct syntax: http://jsfiddle.net/fc5yu/18/